# javascript doesnt load image from url

Tags: javascript, html, url

I am trying to make kind of online gallery, this is first .html doc and when I click on one of image thumbnail it should open html with that image full size in gallery.html

```
<html >
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body > 
<a href="gallery.html?image1.jpg"> <img  height="85" width="85"  src="image1.jpg" /> </a>
<a href="gallery.html?image2.jpg"> <img  height="85" width="85"  src="image2.jpg" /> </a>
<a href="gallery.html?image3.jpg"> <img  height="85" width="85"  src="image3.jpg" /> </a>
</body>
</html>
```

gallery.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script language = "javascript">
function getUrl(){
var url = window.location.search;
path = url.substring(1);
changeImage(path);
}

function changeImage(path){
var imgDest = document.getElementById("image");
var imgSrc = path;
imgDest.setAttribute("src", imgSrc);
}
</script>
<title>Galerry</title>
</head>
<body>
<img src="" id="image"/>
<br>
</body>
</html>
```

all images and .html docs are in same folder... also there are some .jpg images which names has spaces in them, so click on them puts %20 in adrress bar instead of the space, I know that %20 replaces space, but is the problem maybe there? I thought so, but it want load image with regular name too. Any idea how could I load these images?

regards

Comment: are you sure that `path = url.substring(1);` gets `imageX.jpg` from the URL?

Comment: You are not calling getUrl() function... and make sure that 'path' var in getUrl() is getting correct path (you can use an alert there)..

Comment: yes, path was correct, problem was pretty obvious, I didnt have onload in body :s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me that your javascript functions is never called. Edit your script so it is being called on page load:

```
<script language="javascript">
// Assign an anonymous function to the onload event
window.onload = function(){
    // Place code to execute here.
}
</script>
```

Or, edit your `<body>` tag:

```
  <body onload="getUrl();">
```

Comment: tnx, that was it, guess I should rest now, not seeing obvious things :)